# How to include more than one module in PYTHONHUNTER environment variable

Tags: python, python-hunter

[Python Hunter](https://python-hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) can be activated from command-line like below to trace execution of Python programs.

```
$ PYTHONHUNTER="module='os.path'" python yourapp.py
```

But how to specify more than one module for `module` filter?

Answer (score 0):

More than one module can be specified using `module_in` filter

```
$ PYTHONHUNTER="module_in=['os.path','os.errno']" python yourapp.py
```